# What's a word/phrase for "a place what's so dark you can't see anything in it"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Example sentence:

> He didn't know why he killed the victim. Maybe the reason was hidden
>   in a __ corner within himself.

I checked dark on [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dark?s=t), but the synonyms only refers to light, not to the fact that you can't see.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just an opinion: I think *dark* is good enough if you make it flow a little better, like, *Maybe the reason was hidden in the darkest corner of his mind*.

Comment: Too bad we have lost the original meaning of _**occult**_, because that is a perfect fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common idiom is pitch dark, i.e. as dark as pitch (tar). Pitch black is also used to describe the colour of something.

[The Phrase Finder: pitch dark](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pitch-dark.html)